# Pig Action in Oozie - Unable to use pig Parameter file in workflow

Tags: apache-pig, oozie

## Use the Pig's parameter file in Oozie.

Provided the parameter file with argument element. It ended in launch error. Below is the error

```
" APP[visit_c] JOB[0000079-160420073357222-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000079-160420073357222-oozie-oozi-W@pcount] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2] "
```

Do we have an option to pass parameter's in a file to Oozie?. Thanks in advance for your help

*..
..*

```
<script>${pigScript}</script> <argument>-param_file</argument>
<argument>parameter_file</argument> ..
```

..

Comment: yes you can, that file should be present in HDFS.. Can you post the entire error with the pigscript?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had the file in HDFS and still faced the issue. Issue resolved after referring [link] (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Pig+Cookbook). Case 3 in this link had options for using parameter file. I just moved the parameter file into 'lib' directory under workflow application.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after referring [link] (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Pig+Cookbook). Case 3 in this link had options for using parameter file. I just moved the parameter file into 'lib' directory under workflow application.